# Can't figure out what's wrong with my insert into statement to insert data from a windows forms textbox to a row in ms access database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access, sql-insert

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=chessclub.accdb");

    static OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    static OleDbDataReader reader;
    int count = 0;
    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btncreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (con.State.Equals(System.Data.ConnectionState.Open))
            con.Close();

        con.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO chess1db( names , schoolid , major , gender) + VALUES ( '" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtid.Text + "','" + txtmajor.Text + "','" + txtgndr.Text + "')";
        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Record submitted ");
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Every time I press the button to send data to the db it tells me there's a syntax error in my `INSERT INTO` statement. What's wrong with it?

Comment: _Names_ is a reserved word. Write it between square brackets.  And do not concatenate strings to build sql text. What if one of your textboxes contains a single quote?

Comment: What would happen if `txtname.Text` contained `';drop table chess1db;'`? Please use parameterized inputs. In the meanwhile, print your `CommandText` into the console or debug window and try running it in a sql window.

Comment: @SimonWilson That will not work with ms-access. Still correct advice though.

Comment: Have you put breaks and see tha value of your insert query?

Comment: Use command Parameters and all these problems go away, provided that you don't use common terms to name your Fields (maybe add a prefix, e.g., `fName`), could be a [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/reserved-words), or specify all Column names in square brackets -- You should also NOT store the Connection object (and all other OleDb objects, especially with an Access db), you should declare the Connection (and all other disposable objects) with `using` statements right before it's used

Answer (score 1):

It's the plus-sign. Remove it:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO chess1db( names , schoolid , major , gender)  VALUES ('" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtid.Text + "','" + txtmajor.Text + "','" + txtgndr.Text + "')";
```

But do use *parameters*.

Comment: I removed it, still doesn't work, any other ideas?

Comment: Well, the + sign is a typo, Names is still a reserved word. Write it as _[Names]_ or change the column name

Comment: Could be that id is numeric. If so, no quotes: `"'," + txtid.Text + ",'"`.

Comment: Sure, but it shouldn't be an exception for a syntax error.

Comment: Adding square brackets fixed it thanks @Steve didn't know names was reserved, thought it was only name lmao I'm dumb

Comment: Interesting. In Access, plain column name `names` doesn't fail.